# Anything Wrong with This Method of API Versioning Using Flask?

Tags: python, rest, flask

I'm trying to find a sensible way to structure a REST API written in Flask. I'm new to writing such things and I've not seen this structure used anywhere else, so before I continue I wanted to ask whether this is a decent way of structuring my API code, or if I'm missing something.

I have decided on the following structure, with seperate modules containing flask.Blueprint objects.

```
src
 ├──api
 │   ├──v1
 │   │  ├──__init__.py
 │   │  └──api_blueprint.py
 │   │  
 │   ├──v2
 │   │  ├──__init__.py
 │   │  └──api_blueprint.py
 │   │
 │   ├──__init__.py
 │   │
 .   └──runApi.py
```

When I need to apply a change to the API, I'll create a new version folder, then import the resource classes from the previous version and override their methods

e.g. src/api/v1/api_blueprint.py contains

```py
import flask
import flask_restful

api_bp = flask.Blueprint('api_v1', __name__)
api = flask_restful.Api(api_bp)

class Vla(flask_restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'gleep':'glorp'}

api.add_resource(Vla, '/vla')
```

and src/api/v2/api_blueprint.py - the hypothetical second version of the API - contains a Resource inherited from v1 and has whatever methods required overridden

```py
import flask
import flask_restful
from v1.api_blueprint import Vla

api_bp = flask.Blueprint('api_v2', __name__)
api = flask_restful.Api(api_bp)

class Vla(Vla):
    def get(self):
        return {'gleep':'florp?'}

api.add_resource(Vla, '/vla')
```

And finally runApi.py

```py
import flask
from v1.api_blueprint import api_bp as api_v1
from v2.api_blueprint import api_bp as api_v2

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(api_v1, url_prefix='/api/v1')
app.register_blueprint(api_v2, url_prefix='/api/v2')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

So, in short, is there anything wrong with this method of versioning my API?

Comment: I'd avoid doing such things beyond two versions, and certainly not do such things on production, because building with fragmentation at the get-go is going to cause issues in the future. I think what would be better, and simpler to maintain, are [Git Branching and Merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging), because there will be less unnecessary importing and changes to code. Additionally Git has [tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) which can be useful for marking code changes that are potentially breaking between versions.

Comment: Hi @S0AndS0, 
Every version (or at least several) of the API will need to remain available for use, so I'm not sure that branching is the way to go.
Also, when you talk about 'fragmentation', do you mean just having v1, v2, v3, etc. or do you mean my user of inheritance in order to not have duplicate code?

Comment: In that case it's good idea to set limits on how far back your versions may go before refactoring code, otherwise it'll become a huge chore to figure out what is being executed. And yes to both as far as fragmentation, while what you're doing is great for prototyping and quick tests, when a code base gets more complex tracing the stack is going to become time consuming (and cognitively taxing) if ya aren't staying on-top of merging features, side-effects, and such... I've a few projects that are _stillborn_ (forever unpublished), because it's to much of a pain to get back into the _flow_.

Comment: I'm hoping that there wont be too many versions, but I know from experience that there's no way to predict everything so preparing for versioning is a necessary evil. 
However, I do appreciate the point of trying to keep things simple. In the past I've implemented things that I thought would be time savers, but actually ended up causing so much complexity that they made things _much_ harder to debug cost significantly more time. With that in mind for each version I'll probably just duplicate the api code and alter from there.

Comment: Heh, I'm tempted to quote one of my ancestors regarding hopes... On the vain of keeping things simple; `git commit` tracks changes, `git log` reviews'em, and `git checkout <ref>` reverts (I think of it like targeted _undo_). All of which allows for keeping things more tidy. That all stated, it's your project and non-refundable time, all I'm trying to suggest is that a few seconds of committing changes may save many minuets to hours of re-reading and debugging; branching/tagging is kinda a supper-set of such practices that helps with _bookmarking_ known good states of a project.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking for a methodical discussion on if this is a good idea or are you looking at programmatic ways to do the code you gave above?

Comment: The former. The code above, albeit basic, is already working. 
I just wanted to run this by people who've got more experience than I do in order to avoid complications down the road.